# Tomcat doesn't render a jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, intellij-idea

Why Tomcat doesn't render a jsp page? In case I'm telling to servlets container URL: `http://localhost:8080/contacts` than it's all right (since controller handles GET - request), but whenever I directly tell to Tomcat where is jsp in project physically `http://localhost:8080/WEB-INF/views/list.jsp` than get

> 404 error

This is the IntelliJ IDEA project structure:

[image]

My `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--support @Service, @Repository -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- teg library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/contacts")
public class ContactController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String list(Model model) {


        return "list";
    }
}
```

jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>

<%--
  Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
  User: Игорь
  Date: 07.10.2017
  Time: 13:18
  To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
--%>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<% System.out.println("Inside JSP file!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"); %>

<h1>Contact Listing</h1>


SOME MESSAGE!

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: '@RequestMapping("/contacts")' tells Tomcat where your web application root is. Since 'WEB-INF/views' is not part of the servlet mapping, Tomcat is unable to retrieve list.jsp.

Comment: @dsp_user what you say here is wrong on a couple of levels. `@RequestMapping("/contacts")` tells the Spring servlet when to direct incoming requests to this controller. `/contacts` is *relative* to the web application root + the Spring servlet mapping url pattern. It's not the application root itself. i.e. `<webapp-root>/spring-servlet-mapping/contacts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in §10.5 of the servlet specification:

> ... except for the case where static resources are packaged in JAR files, any requests from the client to access the resources in WEB-INF/ directory must be returned with a SC_NOT_FOUND(404) response.

i.e. the only accessible resources in the WEB-INF directory of a web application are those that have been packaged in web-fragment jars.

You may include or forward to a JSP (or other resource) in the WEB-INF directory using a request dispatcher, but the client may not access it directly.

This prevents an end user from accessing potentially sensitive information that may be part of your configuration or in the class files themselves.